# Maintaining a Drupal site for 200 users

Tags: php, drupal

We are building an Intranet system using Drupal. We estimate 200 users to start using this site by next year.

At the risk of sounding such a noob (my role in non-profit requires me to), is there anything at all that I should be concerned with this amount of users? Anything on the server side?

Comment: Stress-test the site before you dive into optimization, you have tools such as siege which can bombard your site with requests which can show you how it'll behave under stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal is great enough to handle lot of traffic and users. Mine handles 3k users with daily average traffic of 10k. You should read load testing reports of drupal like this one http://loadstorm.com/2009/09/load-testing-drupal-anonymous-users/

Still consider doing load testing of site before putting it to production environment.